# Different Different charges on each payment transaction

Tags: shopify, payment-gateway, payment, shopify-app

I am developing one shopify app and I want to integrate the stripe payment and In future paypal also.

I want to set the different different charges on each payment transaction given example below

Whenever any customer pay for the order then below deduction generate from the total amount:

Shopify Transaction fees(x% amount)
Stripe charges(x% amount)
App Platform charges(x% amount)
Shipping company charges(x% amount)
Any other charges(x% amount)
Remaining amount to store owner account
So is it possible in shopify? Please guide me about this.

Also, is it possible with shopify default payment gateway or custom payment gateway? If yes then please provide the details

In advance thanks to everyone for help in this!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to [pass the payment processing fees on to your consumers](https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers)? (This might be illegal depending on your jurisdiction, by the way. I'm just making sure I understand.)

Comment: No, I don't mean this. I just want like development app platform charge and shipping charge on every transaction from the store owner profit. Just divide the customer amount into the different vendor.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Stripe as your payment gateway, it takes a percentage off every transaction. As of this writing, the integrated price plan takes 3.4% + $0.50 per successful card charge. Refer to https://stripe.com/en-sg/pricing#pricing-details for the latest price plan.

The process you described likely isn't supported on Stripe and Shopify, or at least not to my knowledge. Your best option is to do a payout to your business bank account, then do further deduction based using your internal tools.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Shopify and Stripe automatically deduction but for the app platform charges and shipping charges is there any option?